# How do dividends work on GLBSE?

Tags: trading, glbse

I found a GLBSE ticker that I want to invest in. The people behind it claim that it pays dividends (see http://www.blockminers.com/index.php). If I buy this stock on GLBSE, where do my dividends go? Into my GLBSE account balance?

Comment: While I love seeing the GLBSE service and community grow, I wonder if that is too far off-topic for Bitcoin stack exchange.

Comment: @StephenGornick Bitcoin spawns a bitcoin-stock-market and you think it's off-topic? It's so plainly in-topic for me, I cannot even begin to imagine why you think that, sorry.

Comment: @StephenGornick I wouldn't phrase it so harshly, but I agree this is on-topic. We discuss many other Bitcoin-affiliated companies - MtGox, various pools, companies offering services/products for Bitcoins - why should GLBSE be treated any differently?

Comment: GLBSE has closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dividends do indeed go into your GLBSE account balance, which you can withdraw to a Bitcoin address if you so wish. ([Source](https://glbse.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=14#p59))